# How to delete a uitableview row on a button action in swift?

Tags: uitableview, swift2

I want to delete a `UITableView` row on a uibutton action in swift.

Comment: Please provide your research and code snippet.

Comment: I am having multiple rows in a uitableview, I want to delete a specific row on a button action.

Comment: Show the code you have tried till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is pretty much this :

```
func myButtonMethod(sender : UIButton!) {
   self.dataSource.removeAtIndex(myIndex) // dataSource being your dataSource array
   self.tableview!.reloadData()
// you can also call this method if you want to reduce the load, will also allow you to choose an animation  
//self.tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: myIndex, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: nil)
}
```

add a method like this as target of your button :

```
 self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "myButtonMethod:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: reloading entire table view is processing overhead. calling 'deleteRowsAtIndexPaths' is enough.

Comment: the button exists in the UICell class, how can we access the self.myButton though?

Comment: @YashJain you can create a custom setter for your cell and remove everything in the prepareForReuse method of the UITableViewCell. Please check the code here for proper example (there is no button but it should help you noneless) : https://github.com/tirrorex/Sample-iOS-project-for-technical-test/blob/master/TestNumendo/CityWeatherDetail/View/CityWeatherDetailTableViewCell.swift

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like:

```
@IBAction func removeCell() {
    self.dataSource.removeAtIndex(index) // this is the dataSource array of your tableView
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
}
```

Connect this `IBAction` to `touchUpInside` action of your button. Make sure you remove the element from your data source first and then you can remove it from your table view.

If you don't want to animate the removal of your row you can simple replace that line of code with `tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 2):

Try this also:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
   rowIndex = indexPath.row          // declare a global variable
}

@IBAction func reomveButton(_ sender: Any) 
{
   self.array.remove(at: rowIndex)
   TableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little explanation...
For Swift 4, Swift 5...
First declare class variable:

```
var indexForCell = Int()
```

Then make IBAction for removal of row:

```
@IBAction func removeRow(_ sender: Any) { 
    self.modelArray.remove(at: indexForCell)
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Change default value of index variable to match indexPath:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    indexForCell = indexPath.row
}
```

Finally, add action to your reusable cell button:

```
myRemoveButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.removeRow), for: .touchDown)
```

This will remove every instance of a row with myRemoveButton.